# Linear independence of roots

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Given an irreducible polynomial $P(x)\in K[x]$ where $K$ is a field, what are the criteria for the roots of $P$ to be linearly independent over $K$?

Edit: fixed in response to comments below

Comment: I think you mean "What are the criteria for the roots of $P$ in its splitting field to be linearly independent over $K$?"

Comment: Trivial case: If the trace (second-highest coefficient of $P$) is zero, the roots are dependent.